# How do i use my reference in string form

Tags: c#, .net, resources

I am trying to inject a file into another machine... I know how to inject it from a file in the current folder of my application, but the problem is I want to inject it from my resources but it must be in this format Sendfile(string filepath). How would i go about doing that. Currently i am doing this: `SendFile(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "file.rrl")` but I want to use resources, thanks.

Comment: We'll need a little more to go on, as we know nothing of your environment.  Do you have control of the `SendFile` method?  Are these resources embedded in your application?

Comment: no i do not have control of sendfile method